# Center array headers but right justify numbers in columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, arrays

I'd like to center my headers but right-justify the numbers in the columns.

```
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
x & y & (x-\overline{x}) & (y-\overline{y}) & (x-\overline{x})(y-\overline{y}) & (x-\overline{x})^2\\\hline
10 & 31 & -20 & -36 & 720 & 400\\
20 & 44 & -10 & -23 & 230 & 100\\
30 & 66 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
40 & 90 & 10 & 23 & 230 & 100\\
50 & 104 & 20 & 37 & 740 & 400\\\hline
150 & 335 & & & 1920 & 1000
\end{array}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the header via `multicolumn{1}{c|}{content}` to the first two columns where `centering` alignment fails. Here the alignment specifier is changed to `{r|r|r|r|r|r|r}`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{x}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{y}&(x-\overline{x}) &(y-\overline{y}) &(x-\overline{x})(y-\overline{y}) & (x-\overline{x})^2\\\hline
10 & 31 & -20 & -36 & 720 & 400\\
20 & 44 & -10 & -23 & 230 & 100\\
30 & 66 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
40 & 90 & 10 & 23 & 230 & 100\\
50 & 104 & 20 & 37 & 740 & 400\\\hline
150 & 335 & & & 1920 & 1000
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Update:** Based on Dan's comment below that `centering` only works for `p{}-type` cell. One can take a more general approach as shown below, where `multicolumn{1}{c|}{content}` are used throughout the header. However, the `centering` works for that case is the fact that the contents take less spaces when compared with their corresponding headers. Same reasoning for the first two columns (single x and y) and those requires `multicolumn` technique.

```
\[
\begin{array}{r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{x}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{y}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{(x-\overline{x})} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(y-\overline{y})} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{(x-\overline{x})(y-\overline{y})} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(x-\overline{x})^2}\\ \hline
10 & 31 & -20 & -36 & 720 & 400\\
20 & 44 & -10 & -23 & 230 & 100\\
30 & 66 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
40 & 90 & 10 & 23 & 230 & 100\\
50 & 104 & 20 & 37 & 740 & 400\\\hline
150 & 335 & & & 1920 & 1000
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Those `\centering` commands have no effect. They only have effect in `p{}`-type cells.

Comment: @Dan -- In that case, `multicolumn{}{}{}` will be used. I will refine my answer for you remark.

Comment: Perfect. This really helped today as I continue on my project. Note that you have one extra |r, seven columns instead of the required six columns, but still awesome reply.